# Passing values with GET and then update value in mysql db

Tags: php

I have a simple form when I store values in mysql table `academy`. Also, the results are displayed after form submission. Below the echoed result there is an edit button. I am able to pass the `academy_id` through a get method to `edit_test11.php`. But I am not sure how to populate the results of the academy id and academy name input field so the user can edit and save the changes once again. [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/test/test11.php)

table

[image]

test11.php

```
try {
        $db_con = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        $db_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $acad_id = $_POST['acad_id'];
        //Insert Values
        $query_init  = "INSERT INTO academy (academy_id, name) VALUES (:acad_id, :name);";      
        $query_prep = $db_con->prepare($query_init);
        $insert_result = $query_prep->execute(array(
            "acad_id" => $acad_id,
            "name" => $name
        ));

        //Read Inserted Values
        $db_select1  = $db_con->prepare("
        SELECT a.academy_id,
               a.name
        FROM academy a
        WHERE a.academy_id = :acad_id
        ");
        if (!$db_select1) return false;
            if (!$db_select1->execute(array(':acad_id' => $acad_id))) return false;
            $results1 = $db_select1->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if (empty($results1)) return false;
            foreach ($results1 as $value1){
                  $result1  = "<h2>Academy Added:</h2>";
                  $result1 .= "<b>Academy ID: </b>".$value1['academy_id']."</br>"."<b>Academy Name: </b>".$value1['name']."</br>";

                //GET academy_id and go to edit page
                  $result1 .=   "<form name=\"editAcademy\" action=\"edit_test11.php\" method=\"GET\">
                        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"academyID\" value=\"$acad_id\"/>
                        <input type=\"submit\" name=\"editAcademy\" value=\"Edit\"/>
                        </form>";  
            }
    }
?>
    <body>
       <form action="test11.php" method="POST">
        Academy ID: <input type="text" name="acad_id"></br>
        Academy Name: <input type="text" name="name"></br>
        <input value="SAVE" name="submit" type="submit">
       </form>
       <?php echo $result1; ?>
    </body>
```

edit_test11.php

```
<?php

 //Help in displaying values so they can be modified
?>
    <body>
       <form action="edit_test11.php" method="POST">
        Academy ID: <input type="text" name="acad_id"  value="<?php echo $value_edit['acdemy_id']; ?>"></br>
        Academy Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $value_edit['acdemy_id']; ?>"></br>
        <input value="SAVE" name="submit" type="submit">
       </form>
       <?php echo $result1; ?>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate search button on which academy detail would be shown
have a edit link on that result. Clicking on the link you should redirect to edit page with academy id in get method(query string).fire update query on edit_test11 page and return to test11 page. Search the academy id; your result should show updated data.

Answer (score 0):

After the form values are sent to it's processor php file, have the processor php file echo the results into the proper form value with an option to edit the first post values.

```
<?php
$acad_id = $_POST['acad_id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
?>


   <form action="YOUR-FINAL-EDIT-PAGE-TO-INSERT-VALUES.php" method="POST">
    Academy ID: <input type="text" name="acad_id"  value="<?php echo $acad_id ?>"></br>
    Academy Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>"></br>
    <input value="SAVE" name="submit" type="submit">
   </form>
```

This way the user can edit its original post.